# facebook object title does not show on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about the object title in facebook open graph story. My story does not show the object title under the newsfeed, however
under the open graph setting, I was able to see my one-to-one with the title correctly. It also shown under the activity log correctly like the image below:
[3 http://imageshack.us/a/img443/2920/t9b3.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img443/2920/t9b3.png)
[2 http://imageshack.us/a/img841/5230/a3l6.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img841/5230/a3l6.png)

But under the newsfeed, it does not show the object title. shown on the image below:
[1 http://imageshack.us/a/img24/566/5bi9.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img24/566/5bi9.png)

TIA!